# npm package for vuex module give error after dispatching

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuex, npm-install, vuex-modules

I’ve just made an npm package as a module for my vuex. after a long try finally, I could install it and mix it with my vuex. using [this link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-create-an-npm-package-of-a-vue-js-project-which-uses-vuex/14706/2)
I console log my store and the action section contain my npm package luckily. but when I want to dispatch it gives me an error :(
use it in my app like :

```
this.$store.dispatch('orderiomApiPackageAuth/auth')
```

send me error:

```
[vuex] unknown action type: orderiomApiPackageAuth/auth
```

in my module.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

const state ={
    restaurantInfo: {},
    imprint: null
};

const mutations = {
    setRestaurantInfo(state, restaurantInfo) {
        state.restaurantInfo = restaurantInfo
    },
    setImprint(state, imprint) {
        state.imprint = imprint
    }
};

const actions = { //some action here }
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations,
    actions
};
```

in my index.js for package:

```
import myModule from '/.module.js'

function install(Vue, options ={}) {
  if (!options.store) console.log('Please provide a store!!')
    
  options.store.registerModule('desiredName', myModule )
}

export default {
  install
}
```

and use it in my main.js in the project:

```
import myPackage from 'myPackage'
import store from './store'

Vue.use(myPackage, { store })
```

I console.log(this.$store) and I realize that the action section contains my modules. but I have a problem with dispatch them.

I took a snapshot from my console share it here :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PATx.png)
any help? :(

Comment: Please share some part of the code and the snapshot\

Comment: sorry , snapshot was't uploaded . Now it has been uploaded.@Amaarrockz

Comment: Please add some part of the code as well?

Comment: @Amaarrockz updated

Comment: I wish somebody helped me with this !

Comment: there is a typo, try adding end quotes..... this.$store.dispatch('orderiomApiPackageAuth/auth')

Comment: @Amaarrockz no, it's not as simple as it. it was my typo just here not in my real code :(

Comment: I think it's a problem with namespacing. Would you share the structure of your vuex module

Comment: where is your action for this `orderiomApiPackageAuth/auth`

Comment: @Eazash modules are simple object 
`const state = {....};
const mutations = {...}:
const actions = {...}
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations,
    actions
};
`

Comment: @tuhin47 You mean where I called it? on one of my component